# partial specialization of template class with a template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Bar>
class Foo
{
     Bar<T> bar;
};
```

I'm trying to make a specialization of this class that would be of type `Foo<Bar<Foo>>` where `Bar` is an arbitrary template class with 1 template parameter. Can anyone show me how to do this? Also, I don't want to stick to this particular template class definition. If it can be done by using a different definition of `Foo` that's fine, too.

EDIT:
What I meant is that I want the specialization to be of type `Foo<Foo, Bar<Foo>>`

Comment: First of all, put a space between your `> >`, otherwise the compiler interpret it as the operator `>>`

Comment: Since `Foo` is a template, and not a type, `Bar<Foo>` can never be a valid template instantiation if `Bar` is a template with the advertised signature.

Comment: It would generally be much better to have simply `template <typename> class Foo`.

Comment: @Antonio, you are not right. Modern C++ (C++11) allows such a construction and some compilers allowed it even before

Comment: @sasha.sochka Uhm... I see at a serious portability risk. Anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: Now it's even worse...

Comment: all that matters is that the class should have the member Bar<T> bar; where T can only be Foo

Comment: @ThePetest: That makes no sense. `T` can't be "only Foo", since `Foo` *is not a type*.

Comment: Oh, I thought this behavior was somehow possible but I was wrong.. At least I have an answer now.